# How to make a div float on a columnized text

Tags: html, css, css-float, multiple-columns

A picture to show you the matter :

[image: a div on a columnized text doesn't float]

I want the columnized p to behave like the uncolumnized one and it's text to shape around the div.

Here the html :

```
<div>hey, I should float !</div>
<p>Velit porttitor mattis nisi sit magnis nec et nunc pellentesque! Pulvinar est! Nunc massa, dapibus eu etiam ut? Enim eu vut porta scelerisque auctor auctor, integer. Natoque elit? Vel elit nunc nunc? Rhoncus platea tortor, et, velit integer dis, etiam elementum cursus? Ac cum scelerisque! Sit est turpis duis pid scelerisque eu nec lectus. Nascetur mattis.<p>
<hr>
<div>hey, I should float !</div>
<p>Velit porttitor mattis nisi sit magnis nec et nunc pellentesque! Pulvinar est! Nunc massa, dapibus eu etiam ut? Enim eu vut porta scelerisque auctor auctor, integer. Natoque elit? Vel elit nunc nunc? Rhoncus platea tortor, et, velit integer dis, etiam elementum cursus? Ac cum scelerisque! Sit est turpis duis pid scelerisque eu nec lectus. Nascetur mattis.<p>
```

And here's the CSS :

```
p:first-of-type{-moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 20px; -webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 20px; column-count: 2; column-gap: 20px;}
p{text-align: justify;}
div{background: #c00;  height: 20px; width: 150px; float: right; margin: 10px; padding: 10px;}​
```

What's happening to my floating div :'(

Here's a jsFiddle of it : http://jsfiddle.net/mmYQQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. What I wanted to do is actually not possible. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/

But what is possible (and what I actually wanted to do) is to make an img float in a columnized text.

```
img{background: #c00;  height: 40px; width: 50px; float:right; margin: 10px;}
```

cf the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mmYQQ/6/

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
p:first-of-type{-moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 20px; -webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 20px; column-count: 2; column-gap: 20px;}
```

from css

Comment: Er... Yes, that would work of course. The 2 p would be exactly the same.

But what I want is to make a div float on a columnized text. And if I remove this from the CSS, my text is not columnized anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **p:first-of-type{-moz-column-count: 2; -moz-column-gap: 20px; -webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 20px; column-count: 2; column-gap: 20px;}** from the css, its the one which makes it looks as two column layout.

Comment: The question is : "How to make a div float on a columnized text" ; so if I uncolomnize my text... it won't solve my problem :) But as three people missunderstod me, I think I explained it the wrong way.

Comment: Well - your explanation sounds perfectly reasonable to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

See this [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mmYQQ/2/)

Try this Css:

```
p{text-align: justify;}
#media{float:left;width:100%;}
#media .img{float:right;width:30%;background:#f00;color:#fff;margin-left:20px;}
.clearfloat{clear: both;height: 0;font-size: 1px;line-height: 0px;}​
```

Comment: Like for sheldonCooper : of course it's floating if you remove the column. You can see it in the second p. But what I'd like is to see the div float on a columnized p.